# ERROR in node_modules/@types/glob/node_modules/@types/minimatch/index.d.ts

Tags: node.js, jhipster

jhipster 6.0.0
error when running : yarn run webpack:prod

ERROR in node_modules/@types/glob/node_modules/@types/minimatch/index.d.ts(29,35): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/glob/node_modules/@types/minimatch/index.d.ts(29,41): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/glob/node_modules/@types/minimatch/index.d.ts(42,59): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/glob/node_modules/@types/minimatch/index.d.ts(42,65): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/glob/node_modules/@types/minimatch/index.d.ts(271,50): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/glob/node_modules/@types/minimatch/index.d.ts(271,56): error TS1005: ',' expected.

Comment: Check that you are running same version of node as specified in your pom.ml

Answer (score 1):

I was using a different yarn version than the yarn version in my `pom.xml` and when i was launching `yarn install` the version of my glob  and the version of minimatch in glob have changed so it was no longer compatible with my typescript version.

in short, a careless mistake.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the solution? Thanks in advance